# Font not recognized on Chrome for Android

Tags: html, css, fonts

I've imported the Pacifico font from google to my css like following:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Pacifico';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/pacifico/v22/FwZY7-Qmy14u9lezJ-6K6MmTpA.woff2) 
format('woff2');
unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
```

In some versions of Chrome for Android, this font is not recognized. I tried many different alternatives without success.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try

src: url('https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/pacifico/v22/FwZY7-Qmy14u9lezJ-6K6MmTpA.woff2')
format('woff2');

try to add ' (single quotation mark) inside the url()